# MAC - selenium-java 3.0.1 giving java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/NoSuchSessionException using chromedriver

Tags: java, macos, maven, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am using selenium-java dependency version-3.0.1(latest) and imported it through maven, while running the test suit using testng.xml file its throwing following error. I am using chromedriver version 2.26(latest):

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/NoSuchSessionException

```
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:174)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:163)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:120)
at com.makaan.test.BaseTest.beforeTestTemplate(BaseTest.java:38)
at com.makaan.test.StartUpTest.prec(StartUpTest.java:38)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:80)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:564)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:213)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:138)
at org.testng.TestRunner.beforeRun(TestRunner.java:641)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:609)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1198)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1123)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1031)
at org.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:72)
at org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:127)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 31 more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are missing the below dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Since you have not shared your pom file, its difficult to say what is causing this above mentioned artifact to get excluded.